# cleaner proof $18^6 \equiv 1$ (mod $7^k$) for k=1,2,3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Burton's Elementary Number Theory Revised Edition posits this question 5.1.1

Verify $18^6 \equiv 1$ (mod $7^k$)

The case for k=1 is a direct result of Fermat's Little Theorem with p=7, a=18

I'm not sure of the best way for k>1.  I can easily verify it is true but I'm thinking there must be a more direct way using the little theorem or the corollary that

$a^p \equiv p$ (mod p) for prime p and any a

along some trickery or perhaps an inductive proof on k.

I know that

$18^6 - 1 = 7k$ for some k

$\implies 7*18^6 - 7 = 49k$

$\implies 7*18^6 \equiv 7$ (mod 49)

but I'm not sure how to proceed this direction.

Here is my manual check

$18^2 \equiv 324 \equiv 30$ (mod 49)

$\implies 18^4 \equiv 30^2 \equiv 18$ (mod 49)

$\implies 18^6 \equiv 18*30 \equiv 540 \equiv 1$ (mod 49)

I feel like I'm missing something right in front of me.

Any direction or hints that can be offered would be appreciated!

Comment: $$18^6 - 1 = (18^3+1)(18^3-1) = (18+1)(18^2-18+1)(18-1)\underbrace{(18^2+18+1)}_{7^3}$$

Comment: Wonderful! I wish I had such a facility with algebraic manipulation - more practice will hopefully help it emerge. I've seen these tricks before but they don't come to mind when I need them yet.  The one that I don't know yet was the final step that $18^2 + 18 + 1 = 7^3$.  Aside from multiplying it out and seeing 343 (which I know offhand is $7^3$) is there some identity you used here?

Also for some reason, I can't see how to mark this as the answer currently.

Comment: I notice that $19^6 \equiv 1$ (mod $7^k$) for k=1,2,3 and your approach works here as well since 19^2 - 19 + 1 = 343 (so your other factor in the above)

Comment: looking in general at $a^6 \equiv 1$ (mod $7^k$) for k=1,2,3 , 
which leads to https://oeis.org/A056083 

I'll have to see how this approach works for other values of a than 18,19

Comment: so if any of those factors above $(a+1) , (a-1) , (a^2 - a + 1) , (a^2 + a + 1)$ is divisible by 343, then the congruence $a^6 \equiv 1$ (mod $7^k$) holds for k=1,2,3. neat.